# Error running Automatic1111(webui-user.bat) on Windows 11 - caching/lock issue in scipy

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, stable-diffusion

Getting the attached error when I run the webui.bat. Any idea what I might be doing incorrectly ?

Here is what I did:

1.) I installed the latest version on Windows-11 (*git clone*).
2.) Then I copied the **SD 2.1 (768-v-ema.ckpt)** model into the models directory "**..\stable-diffusion-webui\models\Stable-diffusion**"
3.) Then ran the **webui.bat**

Update 1 : If I restart the computer, it runs fine the first time, but then gives the same error if I have to stop/start the application for some reason. Hence it's some kind of caching/lock.

[image]

Comment: Removing the venv directory allows me to run the command again. I removed all other python installations I had. But that didn't seem to have helped - although I haven't restarted my PC after uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

I have such a de problem and absolutely do not understand how to solve it, because it is always solved in different ways. Today it helped to remove the entire python cache and crash dump from disk C. Also delete the venv folder. But sometimes even this doesn't work, the feeling that win11 is cursed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Check which other python versions you have installed - check my answer above. Hope you are able to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I resolved it:

- Removed the independent python I had installed
- Confirmed my PATH variable didn't have a python in it
- Restarted machine